# canon mf8380cdw printer ubuntu 14.04 not working on 64bit

Tags: 14.04, wireless, printing, canon, idle

hello i am trying to install the canon mf8380cdw from the Linux driver that is on the canon website, version 2.9. Ubuntu is able to see the WiFi printer and it will install it using the 64 bit drivers that i have pre installed thorough the software management program. but when i try to print to the printer it says that the printer is always idle; and the in the printer Que the print job is listed as being complete, but the printer never responds. Any Help would be greatly appreciated because i would love to install this OS on the rest of my pc's but if i cant print from them then i don't think i will be able to do so. Thank you again for taking the time to help this newb.

Comment: Linux is a bit different from Windows in that you seldomly need additional drivers...  Did you try first with the built-in drivers? (MF8000 series or MF8300 series or so?)  If not, uninstall the driver you've installed and try the default ones first.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i have been a little busy but after reading your post i decided to uninstall the drivers and try to use the Linux generic drivers and that did not work, but then i re-installed the downloaded drivers that i had and for some reason unknown to me the printer printed!!! Thank for all your help.

Comment: That was what I was going to tell you next!  >:)  Please accept the answer below so someone else running across the same problem will see an accepted answer.  (just when through the *exact* same thing as you a couple of days ago)

Answer (score 0):

First install the Standard Ubuntu drivers for your Canon printer from the repository before installing the proprietary Canon drivers from their web site.  The Canon drivers update the existing generic ones; the proprietary ones don't work well if they're the first ones installed!